# NameError: undefined local variable or method `console' for main:Object

Tags: ruby

I get this error when i tipe rails console.

irb(main):005:0> rails console
NameError: undefined local variable or method `console' for main:Object

Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're in the Interactive Ruby Shell (IRB) right now. The Rails console is launched from your operating system's command line. You need to be in a Rails project directory for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not typ `rails console` in a `irb` seesion. You use it instead of `irb` directly from your command prompt.